# Copying .exe files from ext4 to ntfs

Tags: windows, ntfs, ext4

maybe a silly question but..

why cant i copy an .exe file format from linux (ubuntu 14.04) to windows 8.1 without corrupts when i try to execute it?

I can copy some others file formats like images files like .png, .jpeg, .iso, .pdf without problems but why not .exe?

Comment: Adding to the answers below, it might just be that the .exe file you-re trying to run is corrupted itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference to copy an exe-file or a png-file. Nothing of them will be corrupted if you copy the files between an ext4 filesystem and a ntfs filesystem.

I assume, your exe file isn't really an exe file. Check it with

```
file your_exe
```

Comment: the file was labelled as data but how come..?

i got it with a friend A using windows to lead for another friend B using windows too.

i was in the middle of this process.

when i got the file it comes labelled as data, but when friend A passed the file directly to friend B this problem does not occur. the file remains executable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing. The executable should be compiled for Windows, which should be the case unless you compiled it yourselves and gave it a .exe extension.